LyX Editor - Matrix - Increase width of columns
I am new to Lyx. While typesetting a matrix, I get this:

It gets rendered in PDF like this:

The entries in the matrix in the Lyx editor look a bit crowded, mainly the columns. Is there anyway to increase the width of the columns? I can add an empty column, but that introduces empty boxes which is something I don't want.
I understand that it is the rendered output that really matters, but I intend to use Lyx to teach math online, or at least see if that is possible. So I need the matrices to look a bit less crowded.

Welcome. // It's always worth a try to look at Related to the right. From there, may be here are solutions, entry points or useful search terms? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103929/make-matrix-inside-equation-fit-the-page-width-in-lyx?rq=1 // https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254943/editor-font-in-lyx?rq=1 // https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417654/lyx-bigger-matrix?rq=1


Tools →
Preferences... →
Look & Feel →
Instant Preview →
On →
OK

The format still will be poor while editing de maths, but instantly close to the PDF output as soon as you leave math mode. This show exactly the same matrix, in the edit windows in the same document, while editing only  the second copy:

However, only to no forget, write 20 times: "I know that LyX is not a WYSIWYG".

Great! Thanks. This works for me! I understand that LyX is not a WYSIWYG. I have been using Mathcha, which is a WYSIWYG editor. The problem with Mathcha is that it is not open source. So LyX comes very close to that.
